# Creating a Dataframe with nested Loops

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, nested-loops

I want to create a dataframe which has 3 columns:

`cols = ('ID', 'Y_Start','X_Start')`

I got it this far with the help of Prune´s answer

```
stepsminus =  -0.0009009009
steps = 0.0009009009
List1 = [] # 35
for i in np.arange(48.34, 48.309, stepsminus):
    List1.append(i)
List2 = [] # 100
for i in np.arange(16.0108, 16.1, steps):
    List2.append(i)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)

df['ID'] = list(range(1, 3501))
```

Now I want to enter the X and Y_start values accordingly. In every Row, there are 100 columns with different values and in every column there are 35 rows with different values. But the values from row to row and from column to column are of course the same values. I wanted to solve this with 2 for-loops,

However THIS is where I am stuck. THIS is where I need some help

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
df['ID'] = list(range(0, 3500))

y = -1
for pos_y in range(0, 35): # 35
    
    x = 0
    y = y + 1
    for pos_x in range(0, 100): # 100
        df['Y_Start'].iloc[y] = List_Y[pos_y]
        df['X_Start'].iloc[x] = List_X[pos_x]
        x = x + 1
        
                
df.head(102)
```

Outputs

```
    ID  Y_Start X_Start
0   0   48.34   16.0108
1   1   48.339099   16.011701
2   2   48.338198   16.012602
3   3   48.337297   16.013503
4   4   48.336396   16.014404
... ... ... ...
97  97  NaN 16.098187
98  98  NaN 16.099088
99  99  NaN 16.099989
100 100 NaN NaN
101 101 NaN NaN
102 rows × 3 columns
```

I want something like this:

```
    ID  Y_Start X_Start
0   1   48.34   16.0108
1   2   48.34   16.011701
2   3   48.34   16.012602
3   4   48.34   16.013503
4   5   48.34   16.014404
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is much easier than you make it.  You're simply counting:

```
df['ID'] = list(range(1, 3501))
```

Apply the same `range` iteration for each of the other two rows.  There may also be cases where you'll want to use NumPy's range slicing to generate your list.

---

**Second part of problem, after OP update:**

The long-term problem is that you're trying to apply iteration skills you haven't yet developed.  Please return to your basic materials on loops and work on those until you learn to think in terms of a loop as a *single* control concept, rather than a series of disconnected operations.

That said, the central problem here is that, although you want 3500 rows of results from your nested loops, there is no attempt to do anything with an index that runs to 3500 values.

The auxiliary problem is that you've added "shadow" variables `x` and `y`, which do nothing except maintain the same values as your loop indices.  As given, you should dump those variables and simply use `pos_x` and `pos_y`.

Now, for the actual solution.  First, we'll repair the loop.  For a give DF row k, you have to extract the `x` and `y` coordinates from your 2D array.  You have already done this in the opposite direction, in your original post.  Use the well-traveled arithmetic to get those:

```
for row in range(3500):
    pos_x = row % 100
    pos_y = row // 100
    df['X_Start'].iloc[row] = List_X[pos_x]
    df['Y_Start'].iloc[row] = List_Y[pos_y]
```

However, I recommend that you do this with a single assignment from a constructed list of 3500 values: just what I recommended in the top part of this post.  Replicating elements and replicating an entire list, are techniques for you to look up, or simply derive from elementary list operations.

Comment: what about X_start and Y_start?

Comment: As I said, you apply the same iteration process to those.  Make a list of the values you want, and assign it.

Comment: I tried.. See above  but something is not quite right